# How can I horizontally center two side-by-side UILabels?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, autolayout

I have a series of labels that I want to center horizontally (that is, along the X axis), like this:

```
thing1: value1
thing2: value2
etc.
```

Autolayout doesn't seem to allow this.  Even if I stick the two together and use the guidelines to center the pair, the center constraint only applies to the first label in the pair.

The various "things" will have different lengths, and I want to colons to line up (right-justified) and the values on the left to line up (left-justified).

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I would separate each label in two: the first label left of the colon (right-justify) and the second for the values (left-justify). Then in auto-layout it's just a matter of aligning the trailing edges of the thing-labels and the leading edges of the value-labels

Comment: Yes, that part is easy, but then how to you get that pair of labels (thing1 and value1) to be horizontally centered in the parent view?

Comment: If you're asking for all of the colons between line items to align, and for each item to be horizontally centered in their superview, those two things aren't simultaneously possible.

Comment: Can you update your question showing how you want the labels with different lengths ? Sure auto layout can do that...

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do in code. The x-offset of the first label should be half the difference between the width of the parent view and the sum of the widths of the two labels. For example:

```
CGFloat xOffset = ((parentView.frame.size.width - 
                   (view1.frame.size.width + view2.frame.size.width)) / 2);

// now position the first label using this offset
view1.frame = CGRectMake(xOffset, 
                         view1.frame.origin.y, 
                         view1.frame.size.width,
                         view1.frame.size.height);

// and position the second view relative to the first
view2.frame = CGRectMake(CGRectGetMaxX(view1.frame),
                         view2.frame.origin.y,
                         view2.frame.size.width,
                         view2.frame.size.height);
```